# SVN - moving folders to the trunk

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I'm using VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN as the client.

I have an existing Visual Studio project that was already checked into an existing repo. The guy who initially set it up did it a little funky so that he checked in all the files in the root level of the repository. So alongside all my project folders, I have the `/trunk`, `/tags` and `/branches` folders, all of which are empty.

What would be the best way to move everything into the `/trunk` folder in the repo AND have it so that I don't have any of those three folders actually visible in my working copy?

I have files in my working copy that I don't want to check in just yet as they aren't complete, so I'd really prefer to do this without having to first check everything in if possible. If not possible, then I'll just hold off on doing it until I'm ready to check everything in.

Can I just right-click drag the folders into the trunk folder and then under TortoiseSVN, select move? That would still leave me with at least the `/trunk` folder on my local disk though.

Comment: `svn ls REPOROOT` outpul, pls, if you want exact commands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Version 1 (server-side move)**

- [`svn move`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) `REPO-URL/DIR REPO-URL/trunk/DIR` for all and any mispaced folder
- [`svn relocate`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html) `REPO-URL REPO-URL/trunk/` (TBT!!!) also read `svn help relocate` before using command.
- `svn up`

**Version 2 (client-side move)**

- Inside your WC, which is (?) WC of repository-root, move all your project's folders inside trunk folder (Use [TortoiseSVN Move](http://tortoisesvn.net/mostforgottenfeature.html) - RClick and Drag),
- Commit results,
- Checkout a new working copy into new location from `REPO/trunk`,
- Delete 1-st Working Copy (the one you checked out from the root of the repo).

Comment: the WC is in \users\me\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\myproject I just did a test run by making a new copy of the existing repo using the client method and it seems to have worked. So I'll just need to wait till I'm ready to commit my current changes to the repo and then I can make the move. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, just noticed one small thing. When i open the repo browser from tortoise, in the root of my test copy repo it just shows trunk, tag and branch and all my project files are in the trunk folder - perfect. But when i log onto the server and open up the visual svn manager and browse to my test repo, it shows all the files/folders still in the root, along with copies in the trunk. Why is that? Can those files be deleted within visual svn or are they likely to cause any problems? Thanks again

Comment: @merk - your WC may be anywhere on HDD, I sugested just check root of WC by `svn info` (URL value in answer). `svn ls REPO-URL` is best and easiest way to check *real current tree*